# golang - Pointer idiosyncrasies

Tags: go

Need help understanding why this breaks. PrintFoo can be called using either pointer or value. Why not NumField?

http://play.golang.org/p/Kw16ReujRx

```
type A struct {
   foo string
}

func (a *A) PrintFoo(){
    fmt.Println("Foo value is " + a.foo)
}

func main() {
        a := &A{foo: "afoo"}

        (*a).PrintFoo() //Works - no problem
        a.PrintFoo() //Works - no problem
        reflect.TypeOf(*a).NumField() //Works - no problem - Type = main.A
        reflect.TypeOf(a).NumField() //BREAKS! - Type = *main.A
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.NumField) :

```
// NumField returns the number of fields in the struct v.
// It panics if v's Kind is not Struct.
func (v Value) NumField() int
```

You are calling it on a pointer, you have to call it on a struct instead, for [example](http://play.golang.org/p/hza5f1MFA8) :

```
fmt.Println(reflect.Indirect(reflect.ValueOf(a)).NumField())
fmt.Println(reflect.Indirect(reflect.ValueOf(*a)).NumField())
```

When you're not sure if your value is a pointer or not, use [reflect.Indirect](http://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Indirect):

> Indirect returns the value that v points to. If v is a nil pointer,
>   Indirect returns a zero Value. If v is not a pointer, Indirect returns
>   v.

//edit:

`NumField` gets called on `Value`, not your actual object, for example of you do:

```
func main() {
    a := &A{foo: "afoo"}
    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", reflect.TypeOf(*a))
    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", reflect.TypeOf(a))
}
```

You will get :

```
//*a
&reflect.rtype{size:0x8, ...... ptrToThis:(*reflect.rtype)(0xec320)} 
//a
&reflect.rtype{size:0x4, ...... ptrToThis:(*reflect.rtype)(nil)}
```

As you can tell, it's a completely different beast.

- The first one holds information about the pointer, hence `ptrToThis` points to the actual struct.
- The second holds info about the struct itself.

Comment: >> "You are calling it on a pointer, you have to call it on a struct instead" - But I was able to call PrintFoo with pointer or struct. It worked either way. Why not with NumField was the confusing thing for me.

Comment: You're not calling `NumField` on `a`, you are calling it on `type Value struct{}`, for all it cares your `a` can be a float or a string, but as long as the it's not a "direct" struct, it will error.

Comment: Add more info, I hope that helps.